# Is it considered piracy to put in game music into music library

Tags: music, online-piracy

Various games I have legally purchaced have music files that can easily found by looking through the game files. Is it piracy to put this music onto a mp3 player or phone if it is just for personal use.

Comment: Perhaps you mean copyright infringement. "Piracy" does not have a legal meaning here. See: [Listening to software music out of context](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14339/listening-to-software-music-out-of-context)

Comment: Many different actions qualify as piracy, from downloading unauthorized versions of copyrighted music from a file-sharing service to illegally copying music using streamripping software or mobile apps (https://www.riaa.com/resources-learning/about-piracy/). Of course piracy has a legal meaning: http://www.aaronkellylaw.com/list-of-piracy-laws-in-the-united-states/.

Answer (score -2):

It could only be infringement if the terms and conditions of use specifically stated PER access you could not retain the music for self indulgence. It's an arguable point to prove infringement for placing a CD on a drive for listening purposes when that was the purpose in purchasing the CD song track etc. Always lean on the customer satisfaction importance and keep your hardware clean. If you have a problem it will only be because your motherboard is loaded with duplicating prints. Just saying.

Comment: You should improve this answer by citing to something. At this point, it's just some words by some dude on the Internet. Answers should cite to legal sources via links in the answer.